# Python: accessing exception message of original exception

Tags: python, exception

I have the following two functions:

```
>>> def spam():
...     raise ValueError('hello')
...
>>> def catch():
...     try:
...         spam()
...     except ValueError:
...         raise ValueError('test')
```

Trying to catch the second `ValueError` exception works just fine and prints the exception's error message:

```
>>> try:
...     catch()
... except ValueError as e:
...     print(e)
...
test
```

Is there however any way to access the original exception's error message (i.e. `'hello'`)? I know I can print the full traceback with:

```
>>> try:
...     catch()
... except ValueError as e:
...     import traceback
...     print(traceback.format_exc())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in catch
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in spam
ValueError: hello

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in catch
ValueError: test
```

but I don't exactly want to parse the `hello` from that string. Is there a way to access the list of exceptions and their respective messages, from which I would simply take the first one?

Comment: What Python version are you running?

Comment: Using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: the original exception is available via `e.__cause__`.

Comment: Unless the exception was raised via the `raise ... from ...` statement, the original exception is stored in `__context__`, not `__cause__`.

Comment: @vaultah Ha, interesting. So using `print(e.__cause__ or e.__context__)` should be the way to go.

Comment: any way to do it without accessing a private attribute?

Comment: @simpleuser Python hasn't private attributes. You are probably mistaking them for _name-mangled_ attributes (with form `__attr`: two leading underscores and none trailing), but neither are. If they were they'd have to be called as `e._Exception__cause__`, which is the most _private_ access that Python has.

Comment: @simpleuser What about str(e) to get yout error message? `str(ValueError("Some error message"))` returns "Some error message".